# How to concatenate two layers in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I want to rebuild a customized UNET in tensorflow.js, but I struggle to concatenate layers like described in the decoder block class:

```
class decoder_block(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, in_c, out_c):
        super().__init__()
        self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_c, out_c, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
        self.conv = conv_block(out_c+out_c, out_c)     
    def forward(self, inputs, skip):
        x = self.up(inputs)
        x = torch.cat([x, skip], axis=1)
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x
```

from https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/unet-implementation-in-pytorch-idiot-developer-da40d955f201

However, in tensorflow.js it seems not to be straightforward. For testing I tried to concatenate a layer with itself to have not any kind of dimension issues:

```
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
        kernelSize: [3, 3],
        filters: 64,
        strides: 1,
        activation: 'relu',
        kernelInitializer: 'randomUniform',
        name:"s1"
    }));
    console.log(model.getLayer("s1").getWeights())
    const concatLayer = tf.layers.concatenate();
    const output = concatLayer.apply(
          model.getLayer("s1").getWeights()
         ,model.getLayer("s1").getWeights());
```

But I got the following error:

```
var _this = _super.call(this, message) || this;

                           ^
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got input shapes: [[3,3,64,64],[64]]
```

So is there a way to do the above in tensorflow.js?